# Conflicts with Laravel authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I created a Laravel app with a basic master.blade.php, header & footer and then my home.blade.php.

In my routes.php, I have:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

This was working fine until I ran the `php artisan make:auth` command. Now I have this in my routes:

```
Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

And my previous home page I created is now using the new views that it auto created.

What's the correct way to get back to my previous home design?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel docs says that only run it on fresh installation. You did not. Simple.

If you are using git, just revert to an earlier version.

Maybe you can get something using file recovery tools too.

I don't think there is a clean general solution for you, sorry.